# How to write Python program with output like this: Limit: 18 The consecutive sum: 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 + 6 = 21

Tags: python, sum, numbers

My code looks like this at the moment:

```
    limit = int(input("Limit:"))
    number = 1
    sum = 1

    while sum < limit:
        number = number + 1
        sum = sum + number

    print(f"The consecutive sum:{sum}")
```

Comment: Don't overwrite python keywords such as `sum`.

Comment: Looks you already wrote this program. Does it not work? What's the issue with it?

Comment: You build up the `str` `'1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 + 6'` while you are building up the actual sum.

Comment: Hint: `'1' + ' +' == '1 +'`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the numbers you're using in a separate list. Then use `str.join()` to join these numbers with a `' + '`.

```
limit = int(input("Limit:"))
number = 1
total = number
numbers = [str(number)]

while total < limit:
    number = number + 1
    total = total + number
    numbers.append(str(number)) # Need to convert to string here because str.join() wants a list of strings

print(f"The consecutive sum: {' + '.join(numbers)} = {total}")
```

Which prints the required output:

```
The consecutive sum: 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 + 6 = 21
```

Answer (score 0):

```
limit = int(input("Limit:"))
number = 1
sum = 1
print("The consecutive sum: 1", end = " ")
while sum < limit:
    number += 1
    sum +=  number
    print(f'+ {number}', end = " ")

print(f'= {sum}')
```

Output Will Be:

```
Limit:18 
The consecutive sum: 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 + 6 = 21
```